# CART & stationarity assumptions

Tags: cart

I have a question regarding if there are any stationarity requirements for a regression tree.

If I were to regress 2 share prices on each other (normal linear regression), it would be classified as spurious regression due to the non-stationarity of the data ((stochastic) trend in the share prices). So in order to correct that we would regress the log returns (log returns hopefully yielding a stationary series) on each other  - please correct if wrong.

But with a regression tree there are no distributional assumptions - nor t-tests, etc. So should I be doing a regression tree based on the log returns of the share prices or on the share prices themselves? Which would be more appropriate

I initial thoughts are that using stationary series in the data would be better but seek more of an understanding why

Thank you for any help